# How to do SSH tunneling with docker (machine & compose)?

Tags: mongodb, ssh, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a mongoDB container running on an instance built with `docker-machine`, maintained with `docker-compose`. The mongoDB process isn't exposed to external traffic.

I want to connect to the remote mongoDB server using a GUI tool installed locally and without exposing any ports on the remote machine.

What's the best way to do this? Is there any way I can tunnel the connection via ssh with the `docker-machinie ssh` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the best way to do this? Is there any way I can tunnel the
>   connection via ssh with the docker-machinie ssh command?

Yes. [Per the docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/), `docker-machine` invokes the standard OpenSSH client. You can use the same `-L` syntax that you'd normally use for SSH tunneling. The end of the doc has an example using port `8080`.